# How to store fetched bulk values into single variable and insert all values it on one variable using pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

**Note**

Somebody Tell me how to store Multiples rows value for a single column store into a single variable and behalf of that variable returned values store in table on one single click how to do such scenario using pl/sql.

**Like** Such Query Return single column with Multi rows i want to store it into some var and insert all values on single click process.It will generate error image of error has attached

[image]

```
    DECLARE
    l_respondent_id   VARCHAR(100);
BEGIN
    FOR c IN (
        SELECT
            s.gr_number
        FROM
            student s
            LEFT JOIN class_time ct ON ct.class_id = s.class_id
                                       AND instr(s.class_time, ct.class_time) > 0
        WHERE
            upper(TRIM(ct.class_id)) = upper(TRIM(:app_user))
            AND s.gr_number IS NOT NULL
            AND is_active_flg = 'Y'
    ) LOOP
        l_respondent_id := c.gr_number;
        BEGIN
            SELECT
                s.gr_number
            INTO l_respondent_id
            FROM
                student s
                LEFT JOIN class_time ct ON ct.class_id = s.class_id
                                           AND instr(s.class_time, ct.class_time) > 0
            WHERE
                upper(TRIM(ct.class_id)) = upper(TRIM(:app_user))
                AND s.gr_number IS NOT NULL
                AND is_active_flg = 'Y'
                AND s.gr_number = c.gr_number;

        EXCEPTION
            WHEN no_data_found THEN
                l_respondent_id := NULL;
        END;

        IF l_respondent_id IS NULL THEN
            INSERT INTO student_class_attend ( gr_number ) VALUES ( c.gr_number ) RETURNING gr_number INTO l_respondent_id;

        END IF;

    END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use a nested table for this, together with a BULK COLLECT and a FORALL.  Simplified example:

**Tables and data**

```
create table students( id primary key, fname, lname )
as
select 1, 'fname_1', 'lname_1' from dual union all
select 2, 'fname_2', 'lname_2' from dual union all
select 3, 'fname_3', 'lname_3' from dual union all
select 4, 'fname_4', 'lname_4' from dual union all
select 5, 'fname_5', 'lname_5' from dual union all
select 6, 'fname_6', 'lname_6' from dual ;

-- empty
create table attendance( studentid number references students, when_ date ) ;
```

**Anonymous block**

```
declare

-- This will allow you to store several studentIDs:
  type studentid_t is table of students.id%type index by pls_integer ;

-- The current attendance list.  Notice the TYPE.  
  attendancelist studentid_t ;

begin

-- Your query (including all the necessary joins and conditions) here.
-- In this case, we will pick up 3 of the 6 IDs.
  select id bulk collect into attendancelist
  from students
  where mod( id, 2 ) = 0 ; 

-- Write a _single_ DML statement after FORALL (which is not a loop - see docs) 
  forall i in attendancelist.first .. attendancelist.last
    insert into attendance( studentid, when_ ) 
      values( attendancelist( i ) , sysdate ) ; -- use whatever you need here

end ;
/
```

**Result (after executing the anonymous block)**

```
SQL> select * from attendance ;

 STUDENTID WHEN_    
---------- ---------
         2 07-JUN-20
         4 07-JUN-20
         6 07-JUN-20
```

DBfiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3113da0e605dc25dab4f527b0193cbcc).

Comment: Thanks But you just get limit data  while my select statement returned 11-13 rows for a single column and i want to insert all of then in such case what should i do?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by writing "you just get limit data".  If your select returns 11-13 rows, use the same principle (define your own TYPE, use BULK COLLECT, and FORALL.  See another example, where we SELECT 100 student IDs ("single column"), and insert them via FORALL ... INSERT into an "attendance table":  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ba8939d1ae6b56dd9e247246682a3fab